# Open source counterpart of estro jQuery slider plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

Is there an open source library that offers the effects and functionalities as [this](http://pixelentity.com/previews/components/estro/) jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of jQuery albums. This is a good list: *[Top 50 jQuery Gallery & Image Sliders for 2020](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)*

However, you have to think to yourself how long will it take to find one and then develop it to how you want it. The gallery you mentioned is only $12, so if you take an hour looking you valuing your time at $12 dollars an hour. I don’t like paying for anything, but sometimes it just makes sense.

Comment: its not just about payment, its more about sticking to open source tools.

Comment: Thats cool the list i posted has a few good ones but its also pretty quick to develop your own and a great way of learning good luck in your search